# iOS 9 Parse (v 1.8.5) Facebook (v 4.6) login crash on FBSDKInternalUtility checkRegisteredCanOpenURLScheme

Tags: ios, facebook, parse-platform, facebook-login, swift2

I am doing simple login with facebook using parse for iOS 9 using Swift 2. 
I use ParseFacebookUtilsV4.framework from parse.

I have exactly followed instruction for iOS 9 from this link.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9

Also, I am using Parse (v 1.8.5) Facebook (v 4.6). However, when I try to login like this,

```
    let permissions = ["user_about_me", "user_relationships", "user_birthday", "user_location"]

    PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions(permissions, block: { (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in //switched ! to ?
        if user == nil {
            NSLog("Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.") }
        else if user!.isNew
        { //inserted !
            NSLog("User signed up and logged in through Facebook!")
        }
        else {
            NSLog("%@", error?.localizedDescription as String!)
            NSLog("User logged in through Facebook! \(user!.username)")
        } })
```

It crash like this. I also can't trace how and why it crash. How shall I solve?

```
+[FBSDKInternalUtility checkRegisteredCanOpenURLScheme:]:
0x10014ec04 <+0>:   stp    x22, x21, [sp, #-48]!
0x10014ec08 <+4>:   stp    x20, x19, [sp, #16]
0x10014ec0c <+8>:   stp    x29, x30, [sp, #32]
0x10014ec10 <+12>:  add    x29, sp, #32
0x10014ec14 <+16>:  sub    sp, sp, #16
0x10014ec18 <+20>:  mov    x20, x0
0x10014ec1c <+24>:  mov    x0, x2
0x10014ec20 <+28>:  bl     0x10020d6d0               ; symbol stub for: objc_retain
0x10014ec24 <+32>:  mov    x19, x0
0x10014ec28 <+36>:  adrp   x8, 341
0x10014ec2c <+40>:  ldr    x8, [x8, #3320]
0x10014ec30 <+44>:  cmn    x8, #1
0x10014ec34 <+48>:  b.ne   0x10014eccc               ; <+200> [inlined] _dispatch_once at
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I had this same issue. When I added this from the Facebook doc to my appliation `Info.plist` file, it worked (under section 3, "If you're using v4.6.0 of the SDK, you only need to add:" part of https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9):

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
        <string>fbapi</string>
        <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
        <string>fbauth2</string>
        <string>fbshareextension</string>
</array>
```

More info about `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes`* [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/3781) and [here](http://awkwardhare.com/post/121196006730/quick-take-on-ios-9-url-scheme-changes).

- Edited per Stefan's comment

Comment: "More info about LSApplicationQueriesSchemes" (spelling :))

Comment: Also stopped crashes after doing that. So, documentation reading is useful sometimes :). By the way, if interesting in your FB SDK version pause app and do 
po [FBSDKSettings sdkVersion]

Comment: That crash used to not exist. Yesterday, I decided to revisit an app I hadn't maintain in two years. Apparently, changes have occurred that introduced this crash. Thank you so much for sharing this!